# Access self attributes without declaring self in class function

Tags: python, function, class, object

im working on a python package and I wonder how can I declare a class, which receive some attributes in the **init** function and then be able to use that 'self' attributes in the rest of the functions without declaring self as it's parameters.

Here is an example code to make it easier:

```
class API():        
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token

    def info():
        headers = {'Token': f'{self.token}'}
        response = requests.post(some_url, headers=headers)
        return response
```

I didn't put `self` in `info()` function because that function is going to be called from the outside, but it will be great be able to reuse the token attribute received in the class initialization. i don't know if I'm missing something so any suggestion will be much appreciated.

**Edit**
If I use my current code, I get an error because using `self` keyword without declaring it on the function class, but if I put it, then when I make the function call I can pass `self` argument.

Comment: I think you are missing all the Object Oriented part in python, whenever you are trying to declare a function which is member of class `self` is crucial. so it would be like: `def info(self):` and when you call it from somewhere else it totally fine - like this: `b=API()`, `b.info()` should work

Comment: Please repeat your tutorial on classes and instances.  You seem to have missed a critical concept in information flow.  If you do not supply the instance as an argument, `info` has no way to identify which instance to access for the `token` value.  You simply left the `self` variable undefined -- it's the same as with any other undefined variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is not a keyword; it's just a conventional name for the instance of `API` that is passed to `info` when it is called as an instance method.

You can't call `info` without such an instance.

```
class API():        
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token

    def info(self):
        headers = {'Token': f'{self.token}'}
        response = requests.post(some_url, headers=headers)
        return response

a = API("some token")
a.info()
```

`a.info()` is roughly equivalent to `API.info(a)`.